# How to install rmagick on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, imagemagick, rubygems

Here's what I've done so far:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev
```

This did not throw any errors, so I think that ImageMagick is installed fine. Then I tried installing the gem:

```
sudo gem install rmagick
```

This resulted in the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no

Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.8


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

What do I need to do to install rmagick on Ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: Perhaps moved to unix.stackexchange?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

I think you also have to install libmagickwand-dev from the ubuntu archive:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

This package contains the MagickWand.h file.

Comment: Why isn't this automatically included?

Answer (score 30):

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev imagemagick
```

Answer (score 5):

I did as following step to build from source

```
> wget ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.tar.gz
> tar -xzvf ImageMagick.tar.gz
> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-x=no --disable-static --with-modules --without-perl --without-magick-plus-plus --with-quantum-depth=8 --disable-openmp
> make
> sudo make install
> sudo /sbin/ldconfig /usr/local
> sudo ln -f /usr/local/bin/Magick-config /usr/bin/Magick-config
> sudo PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/ gem install rmagick
```

Result

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rmagick-2.13.1
1 gem installed
```

Comment: This worked for me when building from source.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and came across this post:
http://www.question-defense.com/2010/05/18/centos-linux-cant-install-rmagick-2-7-0-cant-find-magick-config

After I installed libmagick9-dev i could install rmagick gem without problem.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. `aptitude install imagemagick`
2. `aptitude install perlmagick`

As per [these instructions](http://creativenotice.com/2009/04/fast-imagemagick-install-on-ubuntu/).

Comment: That works fine, wantrapreneur, unless you're working with a team that's using a specific version of Ruby via rvm. For the people using rvm, the list of requirements above should work.